# Docker-compose: There is not are not services registered in Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run all microservices from a docker-compose file and I am facing issues when running the containers due to the issue that have between the Eureka discovery server and api-gateway with the other services. There is a way that can make the discover-server (Eureka) communicate with the other services? Many thanks in advance.

```
version: "3"
services:
  discovery-server:
    image: renosbardis/discovery-service:latest
    container_name: discovery-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - test-network

  api-gateway:
    image: renosbardis/api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_SECURITY= TRACE
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
    networks:
      - test-network

  accounts-service:
    image: renosbardis/accounts-service:latest
    container_name: accounts-service
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    networks:
      - test-network

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      AMQP_URL: 'amqp://rabbitmq?connection_attempts=5&retry_delay=5'
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    networks:
      - test-network

  customers-service:
    image: renosbardis/customer-service:latest
    container_name: customers-service
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    networks:
      - test-network

  transactions-service:
    image: renosbardis/transaction-service:latest
    container_name: transactions-service
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    networks:
      - test-network

  notification-service:
    image: renosbardis/notification-service:latest
    container_name: notification-service
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the docker-compose configuration file, the first thing you need to check is that the `api-gateway` can access the `discovery-server` properly

You can go into the containers and ping or telnet to test whether the network between the containers is connected.

use `docker exec -it name /bin/bash`

The startup log shows that your api-gateway configuration is incorrect, as it should be
`discover-server:8761//eureka`  no `localhost`

```
api-gateway             | 2022-12-28 02:25:27.549  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/API-GATEWAY": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/API-GATEWAY": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

## edit 1

I pulled your api-gateway image and started
And executed

```
docker cp    api-gateway:/app/resources/application.properties  ./
```

Here is the configuration that went wrong

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

You just have to change it to

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka
```

## edit 2

Add the following configuration to `api-gatway` configuration file to see if it works

```
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.registry-with-eureka=true
```

## edit 3

I find that most of your problems are configuration file errors in the mirror
This section uses customer-service mirroring as an example

Its port is set to `0`

hostname is `localhost`

defaultZone is `localhost:8761/eureka`

This is the configuration file of `customer-service` that I modified

```
# Server port
server.port = 8083
eureka.instance.hostname = customer-service
spring.application.name = customer-service

# Memory Database for development Environment
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:customerdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka
eureka.client.fetch-registry= true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka= true
```

This is my visit `0.0.0.0:8888/api/v1/customer/2` the returned json all working properly

```
{
  "customerID": 2,
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "balance": 50
}
```

Comment: After I modified this address, everything worked fine So, it turns out that part of the configuration file is wrong when you package the api-gateway docker image @RenosBardhis

Comment: With all respect, I tried to change but with no success. I change the application.properties of the api-gateway:

```
server.port = 8888
spring.application.name = api-gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka
```

And on the discovery-service application.properties:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
spring.application.name=discover-server
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Comment: Also, I added this:

`
  api-gateway:
    image: renosbardis/api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka
`

Comment: Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to discovery-server:8761 [discovery-server/192.168.16.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to discovery-server:8761 [discovery-server/192.168.16.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://discovery-serve

Comment: After spending time making changes, api-gateway is working but not stable. Also, when I run the other services are running but when I try a GET call I can not receive anything.

Comment: Could you provide some urls for testing

Comment: For example, GET ---> http://0.0.0.0:8888/api/v1/customer/1.  I can not get any data also because the api-gateway is not stable.

Comment: @RenosBardhis I think it's your configuration. I updated the fix

Comment: Thank you very much I fixed all issues.